# Field not updating in controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a visualforce functionality, a Custom Button 'Technical Coding' is available on my page. Please refer to the Images. [image: Please check the Technical coding button, on clicking this button a tab will be opened]

[image: These fields will be displayed in the new tab, upon populating these fields and click apply button..these field values should appear under 'Technical coding' section of Details page]

Currently my controller is updating only 'Symptom' field other fields are not updating.

Here is my controller:

```
public without sharing class SearchRecords {
  //String binded with the search page    
  public String strAffectedPart {get; set;}    
  public String strSymptom {get; set;}
  public String strLaborCode {get; set;} 
  public string hiddenSymptomId {get; set;}
  public string hiddenPartId {get; set;}
  public TechnicalCoding objSymptom {get; set;}
  public Issue__c selectedIssue {get; set;}
  public Boolean hasError {
    get {
      if (hasError == null) {
        return false;
      }
      return hasError;
    }
    set;
  }
  public Boolean isSubTab {get; set;}
  private static String AFFECTED_PART_MSG = 'Affected Part is required'; 
  private static String SYMPTOM_MSG = 'Symptom is required';
  private static String LABOR_CODE_MSG = 'Labor code is required';

  public SearchRecords(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    String subTab = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('subTab');
    isSubTab = (String.isNotBlank(subTab) && subTab == '1') ? true : false;

    selectedIssue = (Issue__c)controller.getRecord();
    selectedIssue = [SELECT Id, Case__c, Case__r.Make__c, Campaign_Template_Number__c, Labor_Code__c FROM Issue__c WHERE Id = :selectedIssue.Id];
    strAffectedPart = strSymptom = strLaborCode = hiddenSymptomId = hiddenPartId ='';

    objSymptom = new TechnicalCoding();
    objSymptom.productDivision = (selectedIssue.Case__r.Make__c == 'Honda' || selectedIssue.Case__r.Make__c == 'Acura') ? 'Auto' : selectedIssue.Case__r.Make__c;

    if (String.isNotBlank(selectedIssue.Campaign_Template_Number__c) && String.isNotBlank(selectedIssue.Labor_Code__c)) {
      strLaborCode = selectedIssue.Labor_Code__c.length() > 3 ? selectedIssue.Labor_Code__c.subString(0,3) : selectedIssue.Labor_Code__c;
    }
  }

  //Resetting the text if any filter (Checkboxes or Product Division has been modified)
  public void refresh() {
    strAffectedPart = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('compAuto1');
    strSymptom = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('compAuto2');
    strLaborCode = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('compAuto3');

    if (!String.isBlank(hiddenPartId)) {
      Affected_Part__c obj ;
      try {
        String queryString = 'Select Product_Division__c, Name, Labor_Code__c, '+ 
               'Id, Area_of_vehicle__c, Affected_Part__c From Affected_Part__c  where Id= \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(hiddenPartId)+'\'';  

        if (!String.isBlank(objSymptom.productDivision) && objSymptom.productDivision != '--None--' ) {
          queryString += ' and Product_Division__c = \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(objSymptom.productDivision)+'\'';
        }

        if (!String.isBlank(strLaborCode)) {
          queryString += ' and Labor_Code__c LIKE \'%'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(strLaborCode)+'%\'';
        }
        obj = Database.Query(queryString);  
      } catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug('Exception ====='+e.getMessage() +'===='+e.getLineNumber());
      }
      //If exsiting Affected_Part doesn't meet the new filter criteria, resetting it 
      if (obj == null ) {
        hiddenPartId = strAffectedPart = strLaborCode = '';
      }
    }

    if (!String.isBlank(hiddenSymptomId)) {
      Symptom__c obj;
      try {

        String queryString = 'Select Symptom__c, Sound_Hear__c, Smell_Odor__c, Product_Division__c,  Name, '+
        'Id, Feel_Touch__c, Appearance_See__c From Symptom__c  where Id= \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(hiddenSymptomId)+'\''; 
        if (objSymptom.appearanceSee) {
          queryString += ' and Appearance_See__c = true';
        }           
        if (objSymptom.feelTouch) {
          queryString += ' and Feel_Touch__c = true';
        }   
        if (objSymptom.smellOdor) {
          queryString += ' and Smell_Odor__c = true';
        }           
        if (objSymptom.soundHear) {
          queryString += ' and Smell_Odor__c = true';
        }
        if (!String.isBlank(objSymptom.productDivision) && objSymptom.productDivision != '--None--') {
          queryString += ' and Product_Division__c = \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(objSymptom.productDivision)+'\'';
        }
        obj = Database.Query(queryString);  
      } catch(Exception e) {
        system.debug('Exception ====='+e.getMessage() +'===='+e.getLineNumber());
      }
      //If exsiting Affected_Part doesn't meet the new filter criteria, resetting it
      if (obj == null ) {
        hiddenSymptomId = strSymptom = '';
      }
    }
  }

  //Apply Search values to issue
  public void applyToIssue() {
    try {
      String issueSymptom, issuePart, issueLaborCode, issueArea, issueTreadCode, issueTreadDesc;
      //system.debug('==>params==>'+Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters());
      strAffectedPart = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('compAuto1');
      System.debug(strAffectedPart);
      strSymptom = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('compAuto2');
      strLaborCode = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('compAuto3');

      hasError = false;
      Affected_Part__c affPart;
      Symptom__c symptom;

      if (String.isBlank(hiddenPartId)) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, AFFECTED_PART_MSG));
        hasError = true;
      } else {
        List<Affected_Part__c> affectedParts = [SELECT Affected_Part__c, Area_of_Vehicle__c, CMPN_CD__c, CMPN_CD_TX__c, Labor_Code__c FROM Affected_Part__c Where Id = :hiddenPartId];
          if (affectedParts.size() > 0) {
            affPart = affectedParts[0];
            system.debug('==>Affected Parts==>'+affPart);
          } else {
            hasError = true;
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, AFFECTED_PART_MSG));
          }
      }

      if (String.isBlank(hiddenSymptomId)) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, SYMPTOM_MSG));
        hasError = true;
      } else {
        List<Symptom__c> symptoms = [SELECT Symptom__c FROM Symptom__c Where Id = :hiddenSymptomId];
          if (symptoms.size() > 0) {
            symptom = symptoms[0];
          } else {
            hasError = true;
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, SYMPTOM_MSG));
          }
      }

      system.debug('==>Labor Code==>'+strLaborCode);
      if (String.isBlank(strLaborCode) || (affPart != null && (strLaborCode != affPart.Labor_Code__c || String.isBlank(affPart.Labor_Code__c)))) {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, LABOR_CODE_MSG));
        hasError = true;
      }

      if (!hasError) {
        if (symptom != null) {
          issueSymptom = symptom.Symptom__c;
        }
        if (affPart != null) {
          issuePart = affPart.Affected_Part__c;
          issueLaborCode = affPart.Labor_Code__c;
          issueArea = affPart.Area_of_Vehicle__c;
          issueTreadCode = affPart.CMPN_CD__c;
          issueTreadDesc = affPart.CMPN_CD_TX__c;
        }
        Issue__c updateIssue = new Issue__c();
        updateIssue.Id = selectedIssue.Id;
        if (String.isBlank(selectedIssue.Campaign_Template_Number__c)) {
          updateIssue.Affected_Part__c = issuePart;
          updateIssue.Labor_Code__c = issueLaborCode;
        }
        updateIssue.Symptom__c = issueSymptom;
        updateIssue.Area_of_Vehicle__c = issueArea;
        updateIssue.Tread_Comp_Code1__c = issueTreadCode;
        updateIssue.Tread_Comp_Desc1__c = issueTreadDesc;//+' : '+issueTreadCode;
        system.debug('==>issue==>'+updateIssue);
        Update updateIssue;
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      hasError = true; // Added by Nishank for Story S-367630
      Utils.apexLogMethod('SearchRecords', 'applyToIssue', '', e, null, '', '', '', null);
    }
  }

  //Wrapper for Teachical Coding search form
  public class TechnicalCoding {
    public String productDivision {get; set;}
    public Boolean appearanceSee {get; set;}
    public Boolean feelTouch {get; set;}
    public Boolean smellOdor {get; set;}
    public Boolean soundHear {get; set;}
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please help to handle this..please let me know any information required here..

Comment: Did you debug and see whether you are getting all the values in fields you are willing to update?